# How to get object from MongoDb using criteria api in java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to get result where `varifiedDate` inside `secondaryParents` is not `0`. How can I achieve this?

DB Structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("577a151859defb33c0f8bf4a"),
    "_class" : "com.nv.tracker.db.model.User",
    "parentId" : NumberLong(1000004),
    "userId" : NumberLong(1000005),
    "firstName" : "Pranav",
    "lastName" : "Rathore",
    "addr" : {
        "address" : "",
        "landmark" : "",
        "city" : "",
        "state" : "",
        "country" : ""
    },
    "email" : "ashish.dubey@newvisionsoftware.in",
    "mobile" : "7879066069",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-07-04T07:49:44.000Z"),
    "activeStatus" : false,
    "imagePath" : "http://172.20.0.210:8080/nvtracker/rest/resource/image/1000005",
    "deviceId" : "78 79 066069",
    "isSuperUser" : false,
    "dob" : "1468348200000",
    "checkAndriodOrIos" : 0,
    "isLogin" : false,
    "otp" : 0,
    "batteryLevel" : 30,
    "locationInterval" : 60,
    "deviceSpeed" : 45,
    "primaryMobile" : "9039101994",
    "secondaryMobile1" : "9039101994",
    "secondaryMobile2" : "",
    "primaryEmail" : "ashish.dubey@newvisionsoftware.in",
    "secondaryEmail1" : "abb@hh.con",
    "secondaryEmail2" : "",
    "isVerified" : false,
    "currentBatteryLevel" : 0,
    "currentSpeed" : 0,
    "subscriptionExpDate" : NumberLong(1498132426000),
    "enableNotification" : 1,
    "enableTakeOffAlert" : 0,
    "deleted" : false,
    "hasExternalDevice" : false,
    "secondaryParents" : {
        "1000003" : {
            "secondaryparentId" : NumberLong(1000003),
            "varifiedDate" : NumberLong(14676286792586),
            "addedDate" : NumberLong(1467628679286),
            "secreteCode" : "18716"
        },
       "1000004" : {
            "secondaryparentId" : NumberLong(1000004),
            "varifiedDate" : NumberLong(0),
            "addedDate" : NumberLong(1467628679286),
            "secreteCode" : "18716"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the user where `varifiedDate` inside `secondaryParents` is not `0`.

Please suggest how I can achieve this. Also provide the best tutorial for 'mongodb using java' with criteria API.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?